# Evaluating replacements for a likely blown capacitor

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

### Background

I have a halogen desk lamp with an internal transformer that recently stopped working (no light when switch goes on; fairly simple failure mode). The bulb still lights upon applying 12VDC directly, and there's no internal fuse I can see. Inspecting the transformer's internals, 120VAC shows fine at the input, and the dimmer pot appears to range reasonably from the range of megohms to zero.

The transformer is a fairly standard half-bridge design (in fact, it's almost textbook out of [this application note](http://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00003902.pdf) down to the transistors used, which in this case are BUL39D's (and the cap is either C2/C3 in the schematic on p1).

### The Cap In Question

[image: Suspect cap after desoldering]

I strongly suspect issues with either the cap, its corresponding transistor, or both, but the discoloration (more prominent when flash doesn't wash it out) makes me suspect the cap first. However, I'd like input on the following things before buying and trying a replacement:

1. Am I reading the values correctly as 0.22 uF +/- 10%; 250V max?
2. What type of cap is this in terms of construction?
3. Other than needing to fit into a narrow space, is substituting a different type of non-polar cap with equivalent values likely to cause any problems in this application?

Comment: Discoloration is a bad indicator of a components health. Measuring its value is quite an ok indicator of its health.

Comment: I would hope there is a fuse somewhere even if it looks like something else to you. Check the transistors' junctions with a multimeter (diode check range), out of circuit.

Comment: As others say - do transistor diode check. For NPN BE and BC present as diodes (anode at base, conduct with diode test +ve on base). A slightly trickier test (4 arms helps) is CE as diode with high R bias resistor connected BC. Said resistor can be a tongue licked finger. Doing this with good transistor produces far more Ice than wet finger alone does. Then consider caps.

Comment: +1. Nicely put question. People tend to vote to close repair questions even though they are allowed when presented as this one is. It is an excellent example of trying to "design" a repair, It's relatively simple circuit wise (always nice), has circuit diagram provided (rare for repairs) and an intelligent asker. Well done :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You also forgot well defined question scope. Was there something specific that I needed to see?

Comment: I disagree with @PlasmaHH; if something has failed and a single component inside it is visibly wrong, that's enough evidence to suspect that component. Upon testing the cap (had to rig something up with an Arduino's ADC, but good enough) it looks like a short, so that part _at least_ is bad. Underlying cause could be elsewhere, but the answer to this will be necessary, if not sufficient.

And thanks for the tips on transistor diode checks; the BE/BC ones check out at least.

Comment: @W5VO No. It's just that I have seen questions which are (imho) excellent but are deemed by some to be off topic and once they get in the voting queue, when I next look maybe half a day later they have been put on hold. While in this case there were no such votes, and none subsequently, I did not want to see this going the way of others for no good reason, as happens. More questions like this one would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll ignore the question of whether it's the capacitor that has failed and talk about the design:

1. Yes. MD will be the manufacturer's product series.
2. This film capacitor looks like a metallized polyester.
3. The replacement could also well be metallized polypropylene. I've seen these used in the same role, snubbing the transformer in a halogen lamp power supply. The replacement capacitor has to be suitable not only for the voltage, but for the typical dv/dt seen as a result of the switching frequency used. Self-healing is also a feature of these caps.

Any old replacement with the same capacitance and voltage rating won't do. Don't put in a ceramic. You could put in a film capacitor with the same capacitance and voltage rating from a name brand and it would very probably work, but you won't get certainty without a lot more information about the design.